# Why is my innerHTML is overwriting style properties of the parent class? and how do i solve this?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, styles, innerhtml

im Aron and im a newbie with javascript

This is my problem:

I'm trying to create new content from a form input in my html
but if you enter to many characters in the form, the new html doesn't break down at the right width.

I hope I explained this correctly. Here is a link to my [site](http://www.aronmartin.com/tester/)

Here is my javascript:

```
function plaatsMagnet()
    {

        console.log('plaatsMagnet');

        $('#magnetcontent').prepend('<div id="magnetjes" class="large-3 columns"></div>');

        var textmagnet = $('#textMagnet').val()
        var naammagnet = $('#inhoud').val()



        var 

        divTag = document.createElement("div");

        divTag.id = "magnetje";

              divTag.className =" panel";

              divTag.innerHTML =   "<h5>" + (naammagnet) + "</h5>" + "<p>" + (textmagnet) + "</p>";

        $('#magnetjes').append(divTag);


    };
```

I really hope you guys can help me! :)

Comment: Why are you giving the same ids to all the div's ?

Comment: Hi Amogh Talpallikar, because i dont know how to create different divs using javascript.  how would you do it?

Comment: I updated tester2 with your code. I had all my script in the head i pasted the function below in the body and now it works. Every created div is unique. **THank you very much!**

Comment: Now i hope to solve the problem why the new html doesn't break down at the right width. Do you know what it causing this Amogh Talpallikar?

Comment: provide a fixed width for the div. have u done it  ?

Comment: i cant vote u up :(    i need 15 rep or something :/   im new to stackoverflow im sorry

Comment: when i can i will upvote it! again thanks very muchh!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 jesCount = 0; // will keep the counter for magnetjes divs
 jeCount = 0; // will keep the counter for magnetje divs 

 // All the ids will be unique, magnetjes0,magnetjes1.... and magnetje0, magnetje1...
// if you can mantain an array instead it will be better.
// I have taken counters as global vars to show different id implementations for each div. I deally you should encapsulate such change in a function.

function plaatsMagnet()
{

    console.log('plaatsMagnet');

    $('#magnetcontent').prepend('<div id="magnetjes'+ jesCount +'" class="large-3 columns"></div>');

    var textmagnet = $('#textMagnet').val()
    var naammagnet = $('#inhoud').val()



    var 

    divTag = document.createElement("div");

    divTag.id = "magnetje" + jeCount; // will increment the current value and 
          jeCount++;
          divTag.className =" panel";

          divTag.innerHTML =   "<h5>" + (naammagnet) + "</h5>" + "<p>" + (textmagnet) + "</p>";

    $('#magnetjes'+jesCount).append(divTag);
     jesCount++;


};
```

Comment: Amogh, thank you very much! :)   i copied your code but when i run the javascript, nothing is being created. where should i place   : jesCount = 0; 
jeCount = 0;  ?  its now in my documentready function

Comment: just make sure these are global and declared before plaatsMagnet gets called.

basically ur id names should be different. and that counter will be a suffix in the name.

Comment: ok, did it and i tried it again. It doesn't seem to work? i uploaded it to http://aronmartin.com/tester2/    as you can see nothing is being created.

Comment: i understand a little now..  i'm trying to get it working! maybe there is an error somewhere in the string? '<div id="magnetjes"'+ jesCount +' class="large-3 columns"></div>');        maybe now it says this: <div id="magnetjes" **jesCount** class="large-3 columns"></div> ?

Comment: Yup. It should be. '<div id="magnetjes'+ jesCount +'" class="large-3 columns"></div>'

the double quote should be after we add, jesCount.

Comment: ahh thx :)   but still not working :(    divTag.id = 'magnetje' + jeCount;  maybe this one same problem?      **like this?** divTag.id = '"magnetje' + jeCount + '"';

Comment: it wont matter here. "anyString" + variableName will always append the value in the end.

Comment: ah ok :D    what can it be?     can you see why it isnt working?

Comment: I tried it on tester2 by replacing current implementation of plaasMagnet with the updated one in my answer.
Its working.

Comment: In Chromes console if I override. the plaatsMagnet with mine and directly calling it works. but its not working if i click on the text above!!

Comment: and you are using the same code for plassMagnet which I have provided in my answer ? I have made changes in the prepend code.

the current code plassMagnet in tester2 doesn't have it.